# SharedPreferences managing between different packages

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, java-package

I'm developing one app, with the package `com.example1` and I'm doing another module to use as a library with the package `com.example2`.

On my module (`com.example2`) I'm using this static functions:

```
    public static void saveLastDownload(Activity mActivity, long numberLong) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = mActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putLong(dataLastDownloadKey, numberLong);
        boolean commit = editor.commit();
    }

    public static long readLastDownload(Activity mActivity, long defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = mActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getLong(dataLastDownloadKey, defaultValue);
    }
```

I'm trying to `saveDownload` and `readLastDownload` from `com.example1` but I haven't got any value on these shared preferences. How can I read this value in a modern way (without any security holes, although I'm not interested in making it private).

How could I do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with preferences : [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

> Creating world-writable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause
>   security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead,
>   applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as
>   **[ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), and [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)**.

Comment: Hello Elenasys.

The reason I'm asking is because MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated from >= API 17, isn't here any other way?

Comment: Hola Rafael, I use BroadcastReceiver to send data and saving values in preferences for each application.

Comment: So I guess that's the only option